# ideaVim IdeaVim - can't go to insert mode after command+v

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, ideavim

Whenever I am in normal mode and I paste text with command+v I am unable to get into insert mode. I tried pressing `i` or `a`, but I get system bell.
Then I have to keep mashing ESC number of times, and then editor leaves whatever mode it gets into and pressing `i` goes to insert correctly.

I am not sure why that is happening. Can you help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is really a bug. You can track it's status [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1603).

Comment: Cool - Hopefully you will be able to resolve this :)
Thanks!